# Laravel 5 website and API using the same app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The application I am migrating into Laravel 5 is a website and its API.

The API is used for the mobile apps and for the website to pull the data.

The website will not be developed to be a Single Page App, because I already have all the views and I'm just migrating the website to Laravel 5.

How can I do the following without duplicating my code?

For instance, allow `/products` to list all my products using this API endpoint (`/api/2.0/products`).

The same applies to all other routes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. I am currently doing this myself. Writing the base API first and then dogfooding it for my own website. There is a good laravel package called Dingo ( https://github.com/dingo/api ) that can give different output depending on where you call it from.
If you call it simply from api.yourwebsite.com/products you will get JSON. but if you call it internally like API::get('/products') you will get array/object whatever you're returning instead.

So I have a website that is using the API to render itself. This way, you only write the API once, and can use it for your frontend website, mobile, or give it to third party developers too.

I hope this answers your question. If you have any more questions, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Glad to be of help ;)

Comment: I just noticed that it's not compatible with Laravel 5 yet :/ Any other solution?

Comment: @JadJoubran  try out the dev version. I think it already supports Laravel 5. "dingo/api": "0.8.*@dev" . [link](https://packagist.org/packages/dingo/api)

Comment: Instead of creating an API as the base, why not create a set of classes that contain the business logic and then use these classes in both web views and API? I mean, hitting the API every time will take a performance hit . . . ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating repositories for your code.

Then create separate controllers for both APIs and Website. Through that your code doesn't duplicated and you can access that repository from both the controllers and return response accordingly.

Comment: How would that work?
ProductController@index would return JSON for the API, but for the website it should be a different method that calls the API and return the view

Comment: Ok, in that situation you need to create repositories for your code. And then make separate controllers for APIs and Website.

Comment: @RavirajChauhan From what I read, Repositories are not supposed to contain business logic. That way, it looks like we need two layers other than controllers: the repository layer and the business logic layer. Is there some real-world code example you can point me to?